# Is there a way to keep adding to a javascript array using the same form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

So I would like to have a user generated array, where data can be inputted by the same form.

For example, when the form is submitted, it adds the values to the array, then the form will reset and allow the user to input more data.

How would I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use [`serialize`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) on `form`.

> Encode a set of form elements as a string for submission.

See the comments inline in the code.

```
var arr = []; // Initialize empty array

// On form submit
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    arr.push($(this).serialize()); // Add current filled values in array

    $(this).find(':text, :radio, :checkbox').val(''); // Reset form
    // OR
    document.getElementById("myForm").reset(); // Reset form

    e.preventDefault(); // Stop form from submitting and redirection
    // OR
    return false; // Stop form submission
});
// You can use arr to post data to server using ajax
```